# How do I share a folder to the public?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

I have Ubuntu One installed in my Windows 7 Desktop. I want to share a folder with a few friends who do not have an account in Ubuntu One and don't want to create one as well.

Comment: This is english speaking resource. Please translate or this question probably will be closed.

Comment: This question is about how to share files with friends?
This is not Ubuntu related, is it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're a bit of a programmer, there is a script at http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2012/04/18/publishing-a-folder-with-ubuntu-one which will allow you to "publish" a whole folder. It requires Python to work; it will work fine on Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm not able to test it on Windows -- I'd love to hear reports from U1 and Python users on Windows as to whether it works!

Comment: If you have another folder inside the shared folder, how does that work?

Comment: at the moment, my script ignores subfolders. It wouldn't be hard to make it deal with them, it just doesn't at the moment :)

Comment: I've windows. it got me 2 hours of very intensive searching, installing and tweaking but finally the index file was uploaded and the files were published. I'd share my findings but I totally ran out of my time. hopefully later I can do it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot share the whole folder/directory.
But you can share all the files in it:

1. Select all the files you want to share, click on them with the right mouse button and select 'Ubuntu One' --> 'publish'.
2. Now you can select 'Copy web link' and paste it e.g. in an E-Mail to your friends.

Repeat this for every file you want to share.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to publish files on Windows using the UbuntuOne client. To share files you have to log-in to the UbuntOne website and go to:

> 'Files' > click on 'Details' > and click the 'Share' button

Comment: But he wants to know how to share a folder, not files.  publishing a every file individually is pretty braindead if you have man files in the folder.  This is what keeps me from using it.

Comment: If you want to share a folder you have - as in Ubuntu - to create a ZIP file containing the folder. Then share the ZIP file.

Comment: That's why I continue to use Dropbox, which allows me to create and share a folder of photos with friends without requiring membership or other tedious "solutions".  I thought Ubuntu One was going to be great until I went to the trouble of trying to use it.  It's really only useful for private sharing with myself.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late comer to this question, but I've just figured out a foolproof way of doing that is mega quick, just 3 commands in terminal (building on the top answer):

```
# download the program script from the internet
wget http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~sil/+junk/utility-programs/download/head:/u1publishfolder-20120417145707-dzynnctfx0qgro9a-1/u1-publish-folder
sudo mv u1-publish-folder /bin/ # place the binary into the right directory
sudo chmod -g+rwx /bin/u1-publish-folder # add read, write and execute permissions
```

After that it should just work:

```
u1-publish-folder /home/robin/Ubuntu One/Worldwide # publish folder to the internet
```

Created a shared [folder](http://ubuntuone.com/3Wk6wDn2urH0Y2mnhZdiZy) for me that I'd been wanting to share for ages.

For a more detailed explanation on this, please see this small tutorial: http://robinlovelace.net/softare/2013/10/23/publishing-folders-ubuntu1.html